# Elasticsearch 2.2 : Cant install marvel plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-marvel

I am trying to install the marvel sense plugin for ES and Kibana on windows. I have ES version 2.2.0 and Kibana version 4.4.0

Here is what i tried to do

For ES

```
plugin install license
```

i get

```
-> Installing license...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugi
n/license/2.2.0/license-2.2.0.zip ...
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get
 detailed information
```

i also tried

```
plugin install marvel-agent
```

but i get

```
-> Installing marvel-agent...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugi
n/marvel-agent/2.2.0/marvel-agent-2.2.0.zip ...
ERROR: failed to download out of all possible locations..., use --verbose to get
 detailed information
```

For Kibana, i knew it wasn't going to work but still

i tried

```
plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest
```

and i get

```
Installing marvel
Attempting to transfer from https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/marvel/mar
vel-latest.tar.gz
Error: Client request error: connect ETIMEDOUT
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request error: connect
 ETIMEDOUT"
```

has anyone faced similar issues? Any help would be appreciated. I did not face these problems for ES 2.1 and Kibana 4.3

I downloaded everything from the ES website.

**Edit**

The offline installation as mentioned on

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html#offline-installation

works for ES but not for Kibana. It complains of an invalid url.

Answer (score 1):

For each of your failures in which it recommends using --verbose, upon doing so you should see FileNotFoundException for the URL from which it attempts to download.

However, I just now installed Marvel for Elasticsearch 2.2.0 on a Windows machine, using the same command as you:

```
...\elasticsearch-2.2.0\bin>plugin install license
```

As you can see, the URL it attempts to use matches yours, so the package should be available.

```
-> Installing license...
Trying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/license/2.2.0/license-2.2.0.zip ...
Downloading .......DONE
Verifying https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/license/2.2.0/license-2.2.0.zip checksums if available ...
Downloading .DONE
Installed license into C:\Elasticsearch\elasticsearch-2.2.0\plugins\license
```

Are you issuing the command from \bin?

Comment: i am behind a proxy but i have the env vars set up

Comment: Have you tried an "offline" install? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/marvel/current/installing-marvel.html#offline-installation

Answer (score 0):

This command doesn't seem to work well behind a proxy and the usual http_proxy environment variable doesn't seem to take here.

According to [this link](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Unable-to-install-plugin-because-of-proxy-td4044167.html), there are parameters you can set to specify proxy settings, but the command there is setup for marvel 1.x. The command below worked for me:

```
./bin/plugin -DproxyPort=port_number -DproxyHost=hostname install license
```

More information can also be found in the elasticsearch documentation [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.2/_other_command_line_parameters.html)

Comment: You're missing the link URL.

Comment: sorry about that, just added it